# JS asynchronous/load behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an application that is scraping websites for data. It is scraping the website in an iFrame. I need to scrape to subsequent website from that same iframe that both have an entry adress that leads to a page with a field and a button. On that page I enter a number into the field and push the button to go to the next page. The problem I have is that when I (coded) push the button, it doesn't wait for the page to load and scrapes before there is anythong there.

`setTimeOut` and `Delay` seem to be ignored completely.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#startbutton').click(function() {
    $('#iframe').attr('src', 'www.pageone.com');
    // Here I start a load because I need to wait for the button to become available.
    $('#iframe').one('load', function() {
      $('#okbutton').click();
    });
    // This is where it goes wrong. I would assume that it waits for the second page 
    // to load. But it doesn't. Adding another load block didn't help.
    scrapeFunction();
  });

});
```

How do I get these timings right?

Comment: Did you mean `on` instead of `one`?

Comment: @VivinPaliath I assume he only wants it to run once.

Comment: I did mean one, because otherwise the load kept firing and clicking ok buttons :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I (coded) push the button, it doesn't wait for the page to load and scrapes before there is anythong there

Actually, it doesn't even wait for the button to be pressed. Instead, you want to wait for another load event:

```
var $if = $('#iframe');
// (1) assign a load handler
$if.one('load', function() { // that says "When loaded (first), … 
    // (3) assign the next load handler
    $if.one('load', function() { 
        // (5) which then (second load) can scrape the content
        scrapefunction();
    });
    // (4) and load it
    $('#okbutton').click();
}); // …"
// (2) and load it
$('#iframe').attr('src', 'www.pageone.com');
```

Comment: Ace, I got it working! Could you by any chance clarify why it operates in this order a bit more? Then I can actually understand it. If not, thanks anyway!

Comment: I hope I could improve it. The numbers indicate the execution order of the asynchronously-called handlers

Answer (score 0):

This will execute the code inside when the iFrame has been loaded.

```
$("iframe").ready(function() {
    //iFrame loaded
    scrapeFunction();
});​
```

Comment: And where do I add this, in addition to the current code or as a replacement?

Comment: Enclose the scrapeFunction() function inside it and it will not execute the function until the iFrame has all the DOM elements loaded

Comment: This doesn't do it. I've got an alert in the scrapeFunction to see when it is called and I can just see that it is being called before the page is loaded. I'm doing two subsequent loads, one for the initial page and then another after that to get to the page that needs to be scraped.

Comment: I edited my answer to use `$("iframe").load`.  Can you try that instead?  It _should_ work.

Comment: This doesn't do it either. The problem is that I need to wait for two pages, the first one with the ok and then the next one with the data on it. Using .load twice apparantly gives problems.

Comment: Yeah, I presume using `$("iframe").load` twice doesn't work for you either?

Comment: `$().ready` does execute the handler when the *current document* has loaded, not the iframe which it might have selected.